# Как написать запрос меняющий дату поставки ресурса в таблице Потребность на 05.11.2009 для тех записей, где используется Песок

Tags: sql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно написать запрос меняющий дату поставки ресурса в таблице Потребность на 05.11.2009 для тех записей, где используется Песок.

Знаю, что надо использовать Inner join table

Пытался так:
SELECT Кoд, Изделие, Дата, Расход, Ресурс
FROM Потребность INNER JOIN Ресурс ON Ресурс.[Код] = Потребность.Ресурс
WHERE (((Ресурс.Название) = "Цемент")) AND UPDATE Потребность SET Дата = '05.11.2009';

Но не работает

Comment: inner join надо использовать по заданию? Или это ваши догадки. А так-то задача решается использованием подзапроса. И насчет "пытался", похоже вы лукавите.

Answer (score 0):

Для обновления записей используются запросы `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE Потребность SET Дата = '05.11.2009'
WHERE Ресурс IN (SELECT Код FROM Ресурс WHERE Наименование = 'Песок')
```